# How do I call upon an item from a list?

Tags: python

What is the problem with my code? At the moment it is asking the question about name but nothing else? I think it is something with calling upon items from a list; I used string, but I think that is incorrect. Can anyone help me with what I should do?

```
subs=["Multiplication" , "Addition" , "Subtraction"]
import random
score=0
def addition_sub1():
    a=random.randint(1,20)
    b=random.randint(1,20)
    question1=int(input("What is" +str(a)+ "+" +str(b)+ ""))
    c=(a+b)
    if question == c:
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        return score

def subtraction_sub1():
    d=random.randint(1,20)
    e=random.randint(1,20)
    question2=int(input("What is" +str(a)+ "+" +str(b)+ ""))
    f=(d+e)
    if question2 == f:
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        return score

def Multiplication_sub1():
    g=random.randint(1,20)
    h=random.randint(1,20)
    question2=int(input("What is" +str(a)+ "+" +str(b)+ ""))
    i=(d+e)
    if question2 == i:
        print("Correct!")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        return score

name=input("What is your name? ")
print("Welcome to my quiz " +name)
for i in range(0,9):
    op=random.choice(subs)
    if op == str(0):
        Multiplication_sub1()
    if op == str(1):
        addition_sub1()
    if op == str(2):
        subtraction_sub1()
```

Comment: `str(0) == '0'`, so will never be equal to `random.choice(subs)`. You can just put functions in a list - `random.choice([addition_sub1, subtraction_sub1, Multiplication_sub1])()` will call one at random.

Comment: Wouldn't the input more clearly be called the `answer` here? Confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice` will return a random element from the list. So the code should be:

```
if op == "Multiplication":
    Multiplication_sub1()
if op == "Addition":
    addition_sub1()
if op == "Subtraction":
    subtraction_sub1()
```

However, I'd like to give you a few suggestions.

1. It's fine to have variables with the same name in different functions. You can call them `a`, `b`, and `question` in all functions.
2. Since the three `if` conditions are mutually exclusive, you should replace the two at the bottom with `elif`.